# Will wiper motor get damaged if windshield wiper fluid got frozen?

Tags: windshield-washer

Can the wiper motor be damaged when windshield fluid got frozen? Van is 2013, 
windshield fluid was frozen in car for only 2 days. I don't think this can damage wiper motor at all.

Answer (score 7):

The wiper motor itself shouldn't be damaged by frozen washer fluid, what may be damaged is the washer pump motor however mine has frozen several times and as long as you don't keep trying to use it, it should be fine.

Comment: +1 - Washer pumps aren't exactly low tolerance high performance pieces of kit - I'd certainly not worry about frozen washer fluid from this point of view. Obviously not being able to clean the screen may be cause for concern!

Comment: Yup just don't keep trying to use it or you'll burn out the motor. Let it defrost then use it and you will be fine.